# Is there a good way to attach two stacked columns that have a 3/4” gap between them?

Tags: porch

I am replacing the decking and trim on my front porch/stairs (taking out 20 year old Trex replacing with 5/4 x 6 wood). Once I removed some trim/decking,

I noticed that the column supporting the porch roof (one of 2) is still sitting on the original rotten cedar decking. How do I attach the column below to the one above? Do I have to jack up the roof and remove the upper column before putting in the 5/4 boards and then re-attach? I’d prefer to secure the upper and lower columns to each other if possible and cut decking around them, but taking out the rotten cedar leaves a 3/4” gap.

Is there something I can put in between to secure them, like one of the Stimpson stand-off post brackets? All the ones I’ve seen are for use on concrete, so not sure if it’d be ok here. Is a good way to fix this without totally rebuilding it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Will need some jacking to remove weight from the bottom of the post.

If the post is mounted well to the roof also, then the roof might raise the post up enough to remove the unwanted wood.  Should only need about a 1/4 to 1/2 inch rise.

Keep hands and other body parts away from under the post in case jack/lift fails.

Use long screwdriver or similar tool to check top of bottom post and wood near by for rot.  Wood found to have rot will probably need full replacement or repair might be possible, depending on the wood is used for.